# Visual studio c# send an input for a game

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to do a program that presses a button, like I would just press it on my own keyboard.
It works perfectly in txt files, or somewhere else, but in game it just doesn't. The game is metin2.

Thank you!

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int spaceCount = 0;
    bool startPressed = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!startPressed)
        {
            startPressed = true;
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
            timer.Interval = 1000;
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Start();
        }
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InputSimulator IS;
        IS = new InputSimulator();
        IS.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.SPACE);
        Keyboard.KeyPress(Keys.Space);
        spaceCount++;
        label1.Text = spaceCount.ToString();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your `timer` object is destroyed at the end of the `button1_Click` method and can't fire anymore. It needs to be a property of Form1 (same as `spaceCount` and `startPressed`).

Comment: The timer works well, and my question was about the input commands, but thanks.